# Cannot import EclipseLink MOXy

Tags: java, netbeans, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I downloaded the latest EclipseLink (2.4) and put the eclipselink.jar in my folder. However, I do not see the @XmlInverseReference annotation anywhere and I cannot import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.*;

What am I doing wrong? I am using Netbeans 7.2.1.

Alternatively, what might be a good alternate solution for bidirectional relationships with JAXB annotations? I have a Parent and a Child class, Child has a reference to Parent because of JPA foreign key. As soon as I unmarshal, the reference is gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I created a `Web Application` using NetBeans 7.3 and all I needed to do to include EclipseLink was right click the `Libraries` icon in the `Project` panel and choose `Add Jar/Folder...` and then subsequently point at the `eclipselink.jar` in the EclipseLink install.

---

The import for `@XmlInverseReference` is the following:

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlInverseReference;
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/03/moxys-xmlinversereference-is-now-truly.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/jpa-entities-to-xml-bidirectional.html

Comment: Correct, but the only thing that's showing up is org.eclipse.persistence.javax. Nothing else. I have a jaxb.properties file and imported the eclipselink jar. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: @user1810737 - I will download NetBeans and post the proper project setup

Comment: @user1810737 - Is your NetBeans project driven by a `pom.xml` file?

Comment: It's a standard Java Web application, without a pom.xml. I might have to refactor it to a maven application...